# How can one find / collect data for, and come up with ideas for, using Deep Learning / AI to improve one's everyday life?

Tags: deep-learning, datasets

I can see a lot of tutorials and examples about using TensorFlow and other free, open-source AI/ML/DL frameworks on enterprise level where enough data was collected for such AI solutions.

How can one can collect enough data in normal everyday life to practically and effectively make use of such freely available AI/ML/DL technologies to improve one's life and security?

Comment: I edited the question title to try and turn it into more of a "proper" question.  I think this actually is a really good question in the general sense, but if anybody has suggestions for edits to make it better, fire away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking to the "collecting data" part of the question, I'll say this:

Keep in mind that not **everything** requires massive amounts of data. Consider also that large amounts of data about all sorts of things are available in the [OpenData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data) / [LinkedData](http://linkeddata.org/) realms. Governments in particular are sources of massive amounts of data.  See, for example, [data.gov](http://www.data.gov) or Google around and see if your (state|city|county|whatever) has an "open data" portal. You might be surprised.

Finally consider that inexpensive sensor systems and distributed sensor networks can be constructed fairly easily / inexpensively using things like Arduino / Raspberry Pi and communications protocols and software often associated with the term [Internet of Things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things).  You may find that you can actually collect your own data, especially if you crowd-source the effort and get a bunch of other people involved.

See also:

http://opendata.reddit.com

http://datasets.reddit.com

http://www.wikidata.org

http://www.dbpedia.org

etc.